# Функция, обратная list()

Tags: python

Всем привет! Как известно функция list() в python преобразовывает строку в массив,где каждый элемент это буква. А есть ли обратная функция, которая из этого массива делает обратно целую строку?

Comment: `"".join(list)`.

Comment: Ну вообще list() не только строки преобразует :)

Answer (score 3):

```py
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print (''.join(a))
```

Результат:

```
abc
```

Работает для всех итерируемых объектов, при условии, что каждый объект внутри данного является строкой

Comment: *>>можно привести к строке* - неправильно.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов был неправ, спасибо. Исправил